# How to implement a custom cell renderer for ScrollTable in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

I've used the [ScrollTable](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ScrollTable) widget for GWT and I have a need for a custom cell renderer so I can isolate this code from the rest of the app.

I would like to use generics if possible to get it type safe. This cell renderer will take a long as a value and do some calculation before displaying the result. Anyone having a good example on how to implement such a custom renderer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about ScrollTable, but if you use `PagingScrollTable` from the GWT Incubator, you implement `AbstractColumnDefinition<RowType,ColType>` for your `columnDefinition`.  You may then override `CellRenderer<RowType,ColType>` and apply it:

```
columnDefinition.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
```